# Set boolean in foreach loop if document exists

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm stuck trying to figure this out and hoping somebody can help me out or point me in the right direction. (I'm new to swift so apologies if this is a stupid question).

What I have happening below is a foreeach loop getting a list if items from the db. On each item, it references a separate document in the db to see if it exists for that specific user. The `print` in `checkUserAddedItems` work perfectly, showing each of the items and if they exist or not for that user. What I'm struggling with is figuring out how to set the `items[i].selected` to true if the document exists, so that it will show the Remove button instead of the Add for that specific item

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
@State var items = [ItemsModel]()

var body: some View {
VStack{
ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
   HStack {
   Text(items[i].name)
   
   if items[i].selected == false {
      Button(action: { addItem() }) { Text("Add") }
   } else { 
      Button(action: { removeItem() }) { text("Remove") }
   }
   }
   .onAppear { checkUserAddedItems(itemName: items[i].name)}
}
.onAppear { fetchItems() }
}


func checkUserAddedItems(itemName: String) {
        
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   let docRef = db.collection("users").document("\(userInfo.user.uid)").collection("itemAdded").document(self.movieID).collection("item").document("\(itemName)")
        
   docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
         print("\(itemName) exists")
      } else {
         print("\(itemName) does not exist")
      }
   }
}

func fetchItems() {
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   db.collection("movies").document("\(self.movieID)").collection("items").getDocuments { (NewQuerySnapshot, error) in
   guard let documents = NewQuerySnapshot?.documents else {
      print("No Documents")
      return
   }
   items = documents.map { (NewQueryDocumentSnapshot) -> ItemsModel in
                
      let data = NewQueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
      let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                
      return ItemsModel(name: name)
                
   }
   }
   }

}
```

```
struct ItemsModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var selected:Bool = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reset your state variable with an updated array of items that has the value set on the correct item.  One solution is doing a `map` on the array and only modifying the one value.

Something like:

```
func setSelectedOnItem(id: String, val: Boolean) {
  items = items.map { item in 
    if item.id == id {
      var newItem = item
      newItem.selected = val
      return newItem
    } else {
      return item
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your `checkUserAddedItems` function, call the above method, filling in the `id` from the document.  You presumably only need to call it if it exists -- otherwise it would stay false.